# I want store the data that i get in response from the customer using parameters at dialogflow to google sheet. Is that possible?

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

i am trying to collect the data that i receive from the customers like phone number, address etc to google sheet from dialogflow. is that possible?

I cannot use the inline editor as i don;t have a credit card to start the billing

Comment: Welcome! StackOverflow works best when you have a specific question or problem you can illustrate with code you've attempted to solve the problem, along with errors you're getting attempting to solve it, or unexpected output (along with what you do expect). Broad questions like this are likely to get broad, unhelpful, answers. The more you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to help. See "[ask] a Good Question?"

Answer (score 0):

You have several broad questions here, so it isn't clear what your problem is.

Yes, it is possible to create fulfillment code for Dialogflow that collects this information.

Yes, you can store this in Google Sheets. See the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) for more.

You do not need to use the Inline Functions to run your fulfillment. You can use any public web server you control that can

1. Accept HTTPS connections using a non-self-signed certificate
2. From the public Internet
3. That will accept JSON in the Dialogflow request format and return Dialogflow response formatted JSON